# Addressing nodes in a tree

Tags: tree

Are there any standard notations to address nodes in a tree?

For example, this is my homemade notation:

```
     0
    / \
   1   2
  / \   \
 3   4   5
```

The position of the nodes could be addressed as follows:

- Node 0: 0
- Node 1: 0,0
- Node 3: 0,0,0
- Node 4: 0,0,1
- Node 2: 0,1
- Node 5: 0,1,0

The tree in the diagram is a binary tree, but I need a solution for all trees.

Comment: Best way depends on purpose.  Often it's the binary number you get starting with MSB and proceeding to LSB, 0 for left and 1 for right, or some such, etc...   But really it depends on your needs.

Comment: In this case it's not a binary tree.

Comment: The diagram you posted is certainly a binary tree, though not a complete one.   If you have an n-ary tree, though, you can make the obvious extension to base-n expansions...

Comment: You're right, the diagram is a binary tree. The problem I'm trying to solve does not involve a binary tree. Will update diagram

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I needed to solve this just now.  The solution you suggest in the question is fine and straight-forwardly generalizable to an n-ary tree.

The idea is that an address of a tree node is a list of indexes where each is a 0-based index into a node's children array at each level.  So for example, given this more general tree:

```
       0
    /  |  \
   1   2   3
  / \    / | \
 4   5  6  7  8

address(0) = []      // root is [] by definition
address(1) = [0]     // root.children[0]
address(2) = [1]     // etc
address(3) = [2]
address(4) = [0,0]   // root.children[0].children[0]
address(5) = [0,1]   // etc
address(6) = [2,0]
address(7) = [2,1]
address(8) = [2,2]   // root.children[2].children[2]
```

In other words, to get an address for a node (in pseudo javascript):

```
function addressForNode(node) {
    if (!node.parent) return []
    var parent = node.parent
    var siblings = parent.children
    var index = indexOf(siblings, node)
    return addressForNode(parent).unshift(index)
}
```

To get a node given an address and a tree (which is taken to be the root node):

```
function nodeWithAddress(tree, address) {
    if (address == []) return tree
    var childIndex = address.shift()
    var childNode = tree.children[childIndex]
    return nodeFrom(childNode, address)
}
```

Where `indexOf()`, `unshift()` and `shift()` operate as in javascript:  `indexOf()` returns the index of an element in an array.  `unshift()` appends an element to the front of an array.  `shift()` removes from the front and returns it.